# All even numbers have a binary representation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, binary

I have to prove the following:

> "For every even integer $0\leq a\leq2^n-2$ (and for all integers $n\geq1$), there exist binary ($0$ or $1$) $w_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (w_i2^i)=a$"

I plan to prove this statement by writing out the numbers $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...$ in binary format

```
00000

00010

00100

00110

01000

01010

01110

10000

...
```

and noting that if we consider, for example, each digit of the binary number $00110$ (corresponding to 'base $10$' number $3$) as the value of $w_i$ (where $i = 1$ corresponds to the digit immediately before the rightmost digit of the binary number) when $n=3$, we associate each binary number with an even integer $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (w_i2^i)=a$.

**I want to show that the correspondence between the binary numbers and numbers $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...$ implies that we can associate a binary number (representing the $w_i$) with each even integer in the desired range (for all $n$ in the stated range).**

Is this a valid approach to prove the statement in quotes above?  If not, how can I start the proof?  Would I need to use induction and/or contradictions?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: am i missing something? isn’t every natural number represented like this in binary?

Comment: $i=1$ is not the rightmost; $i=0$ is, and your statement to be proven forces $w_0 = 0$.

Comment: @peterwhy I have edited the post to fix the issue; is the post still incorrect?

Comment: @FabrizzioMuzz This is like saying: for even $a$ in $0 \le a < 2^n$, $a/2$ is an (even or odd) integer in $0\le a/2 < 2^{n-1}$, so it has a binary representation with length $n-1$. Then take the bits of $a/2$ as $w_1, \ldots , w_{n-1}$. I guess this proof would work inductively in $n$, if you also prove for odd $a$ cases?

Comment: That sounds correct; is there an example of a proof like this on Math SE?

Comment: The problem seems to be an assigned exercise, intended to reinforce learning of a particular lesson.  Without that context Readers cannot make an informed guess about whether the approach is "correct" though the conclusion is supported by your construction.  However if you were expected to prove this by induction, the grading might be done on that basis.